# Why would a society reject binary logic as useless?

Tags: scientific-development

Long ago, well before the invention of electrical power or electronics--thinking a Middle Ages or Renaissance time period—there was a brief period when the scholars and natural philosophers of the day became infatuated with the idea of boolean logic.

They developed formalized notions of True and False, 1 and 0 and base 2 number representations, AND, OR, XOR, and NOT, essentially the fundamental principles of digital computers. A lot of study went into it, but they eventually concluded that the concept had no practical value, and the ideas fell into obscurity within a generation or two.

A few centuries later, some researcher is working on electronic circuitry and happens to come across a long-forgotten book that tells him 80% of everything he needs to know about the principles of digital logic. Looking into the subject further, he's astounded to find that the scholars of yesteryear had all this theory and then simply threw it away as having no value, because they didn't realize that...

...what? Why would something that today we know to be immensely valuable be dismissed as a mere intellectual curiosity and then forgotten? Would simply not having the technology to build something useful from it be enough?

Comment: I was taught in CS1 that nobody really cared all that much about boolean algebra until computers came around. There really is no use for it except with circuits and computers. The bigger question may be why they did so much with it in the past, rather than why they gave up.

Comment: I can see two ways this can go.  One is that the concept of binary proved insufficiently useful, and was supplanted by something else.  The other is the one that the firmware layout people have gone, needing to expand upon binary with many other symbols to describe their products, but with binary hidden underneath.  Do you have a preference of direction?

Comment: This sounds a bit like Idea Generation/plot-building, which *might* make this off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Historically speaking ideas were abandoned due to political or religious influence. Ethical reasons are possible as well.

China [abandoned international trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheng_He) in 1433 as a consequence of political infighting at court.

The catholic church vigorously suppressed the idea of [heliocentrism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_affair) as being contradictory to church doctrine.

[Gene therapy](http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/handbook/therapy/ethics) is controversial because of ethical and other reasons, and it is hard to predict how it eventually will play out.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheng_He
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_affair
http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/handbook/therapy/ethics

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the Catholic Church opposition to Galileo had as much to do with personal dislike of the man as anything else. He was abrasive in his certainty of the truth of his theory and some of the officials took offense.

Comment: Sean's right.  It's worth noting that Galileo was right about heliocentrism but badly wrong about the details.  His insistence that his model was not only right (which was not true) but *scripturally supported* technically really was heresy, and his willingness to insult the pope for asking for proof certainly didn't do him any favors!

Answer (score 4):

Binary logic can be seen to lead to [dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism).  Or being a result of dualism.
True/False, Good/Evil, Us/Them, Body/Soul, Man/Woman etc.

All these distinctions aren't really as sharp as some people want to make them.

If somebody use this kind of logic to argue for something bad, the backlash can make the whole dualism/binary logic thing seem bad.

Comment: This is self-defeating: if you declare binary logic so bad that it should be banished to oblivion, this is sharp dualistic distinction in and of itself (good world with binary logic vs bad world without it) :)

Answer (score 3):

Your question has the answer within it.

> A lot of study went into it, but they eventually concluded that **the concept had no practical value**

That pretty much sums it up.

In modern circuitry, all the magic lies in the [diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode). This is where all the magic happens and where you can practice all boolean logic. Transistor is the most common form. Before the semiconductor diode which revolutionized electronics, they used vacuum tubes which were heavy, large and messy. It was only after the advent of diode in 1950s that the whole potential of boolean algebra came into practical realm.

Without diode, boolean algebra is only theory with no application.

Comment: Don't forget mechanical relays and early telephone rotary switches!

Comment: Yargh. Must find out what device did they employ for the conditional circuitry part.

Comment: Relays can be used to implement logic gates.  See [purple code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_naval_codes#Purple) for switches: probably not used to do if/then/else but to do transforms.

Comment: Relays _can_ be used to implement logic gates. True. But do you **really** know the size of a circuit built with relays being used as diodes? Enormous, if not totally **huge**. And then we have the added complexity of two electrical connections and a hell of figuring out where to connect which point. Absolutely impractical for anything larger than a radio, I could tell you that.

Comment: In terms of size and wiring, relays are easier than vacuum tubes.  IAC, important historical projects existed, and there were hobby books on the subject. It really is a thing.

Comment: It is _theoretically_ possible to build such a thing as a computer with relays, but _practically_ it is not. Just as theoretically it is possible to build a vehicle running on gunpowder or mercury fulminate (Edison even tried it!) but practically it is absolutely unfeasible.

Comment: Building using vacuum tubes is just as infeasible,  you know.  Lack of practicality did not stop people from doing it.  It is not just *theoretical*: logical devices *including computers* were in fact built using relays.  Vacuum tubes did not take over until they became more reliable: it was originally impossible to scale as they would need replacing faster than the machine could run a job.

Comment: "The use of **relays for the logical contro**l of complex switching systems like telephone exchanges was studied by Claude Shannon, who formalized the application of **Boolean algebra** to relay circuit design..."  It's not "theoretically possible", it's real history of the subject and our heritage.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_programming_language !

Comment: Looking things up for the comments, I learned that your assertion is completely wrong. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Symbolic_Analysis_of_Relay_and_Switching_Circuits  The father of information theory worked with Boolean logic with the wide spread (and *real*) relay systems of the day.

Comment: Yes, first computers were indeed built with vacuum tubes. But then again, costly, messy, complex components of a circuit would limit its practicality for wider use. You cannot expect to build TVs and personal use computers with those things. Forget all those flashing neon signs, digital watches, cellphones and all the other plethora of digital devices that sprang into existence after the invention of semiconductor diode. In the absence of the semiconductor diode, binary algebra would have remained a queer, interesting field of mathematics, only taught in very specialized career courses.

Comment: I read that wiki link. In those days semiconductor diodes weren't invented so yes, he was limited to keeping his analysis to relays. What is the point here?

Comment: That they are/were a real thing (of historical significance), not a pure theoretical possibility with no practical value like gunpowder engines.  It's not unfeasible; it was commercially important.  The use of relays did not cause Boolean knowledge to be dismissed, but introduced as a thing for engineers to know.

Comment: _Long ago, **well before the invention of electrical power or electronics**--thinking a Middle Ages or Renaissance time period—there was a brief period when the scholars and natural philosophers of the day became infatuated with the idea of boolean logic. They developed formalized notions of True and False, 1 and 0 and base 2 number representations, AND, OR, XOR, and NOT, essentially the fundamental principles of digital computers. A lot of study went into it, but **they eventually concluded that the concept had no practical value.**_ Quoting OP's text for you, for background sake.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the uses of binary logic:

Electrical work - it seems like [William Gilbert](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Gilbert_(astronomer)) was one of the founders of this, back in the 16th century, but it wasn't really used for anything until around the 19th century.

Computers - Let's attribute this one to [Chucky Babbage](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) in the 19th century.

Mathematics - specifically set theory, invented by [Georg Cantor](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor) also in the 19th century.

Boolean logic wasn't even really a thing until [George Boole](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole) came up with it, again in the 19th century, and even then it wasn't really very useful to anyone.

Thus, if you have someone in the seventeenth century or earlier playing around with Boolean logic, they won't have anything to do with it for another two hundred years (except playing with logic puzzles).

Plus, there's no obvious backwards connection from boolean logic to these other fields. If you can't even create a light bulb, you're not going to make the jump from binary to circuitry. Even if you do think up an analytical engine, just like Babbage you won't actually have the ability to build it.

So, in summary, just say that it was invented before anyone had thought up a use for it. Then it can be forgotten just like all that other stuff that we don't remember (which could include quite a lot more things than you think it does). As to why it used to be so popular, people used to think the harpsichord and Jane Austen novels were pretty cool too. Tastes change, the things that are considered fun and interesting change too. With no application, boolean logic would be considered just a source of amusement, so all it takes is for something more amusing to come along.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is the basis for logic.  Which is a part of philosophy.  So if people didn't find the philosophical pursuit of logic to be fulfilling then it might get lost.

True, false, And, Or and Not are not just useful for programs, it is useful in clear logical thinking.  Any college logic class uses them all as the basis of valid arguments.

So I would say an entire society that gave up on logic for some other form of decision making, like reading entrails or games of chance (where they don't bother caring about the odds).

Comment: Maybe there was just a large philosophical movement based around the concept of 'maybe'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working from a theoretical standpoint, there's really no reason to prefer a two-valued logic (true/false) over a [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) (true/false/undecided) or a [four-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-valued_logic) (true/false/undecided/contradictory).  On the contrary, the higher-valued logics let you express a wider range of situations.

Binary logic really only shines if you're trying to make a mechanical implementation of it, where three-valued logic is tricky, and four-valued is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they liked questions and problems that are more condusive to Fuzzy logic : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic

*Was it a 'good' movie?*

*no, because it had a plot hole and therefore is not good.*

*I reject your premise that the existence of one plot hole makes the entire movie 'not good'. I reject the entire assertion that a movie is either 'good' or 'not good'. surely that plot hole merely makes the movie 'less good'.*